# unable to connect django sevice with rabbitmq service using docker

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect RabbitMQ with Django application. But when I run the command "docker-compose up" I get this error "pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError" can someone explain me the reason for this error and also suggest me its solution. I am sharing the code of docker-compose file and the publisher code where the main error is.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
#      - HOST:localhost
      - POSTGRES_DB=admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
#      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 15673:15672
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST=localhost
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_HOST=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest

    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
```

produce.py

```
import pika, os, django
from .models import Product

# amqps://bescccok:rsjlBxeksDvwcp23H0QDJh83qttksbsF@sparrow.rmq.cloudamqp.com/bescccok

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost')
)

channel = connection.channel()


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    import json
    print('Received in admin')
    id = json.loads(body)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    product.likes = product.likes + 1
    print("Product Liked!!! ")


channel.basic_consume(queue='admin', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print("Started Consuming")

channel.start_consuming()

channel.close()
```

I tried to changing the hostname in docker-compose file in rabbitmq service and add the servicein pika connection function, still it didn't work.

Comment: what further output do you get along the exception?   can it be that you are connecting on the wrong port? (you are mapping  15673 to 15672 in the docker-compose file)

Comment: I don't get any port error, this is the only exception I get.

Comment: is there any additional information to the exception? (stack trace, error message)

Comment: I think may be its because of the order of the image building, even though I have put depends_on in backend service but still backend image is building before rabbitmq causing the conection error.

Comment: building order doesn't matter the startup order does, you could start them up manually in the order you want, to ensure it's not the startup order